# Permission denied error when trying to run Atom

Tags: atom

Below is the error I get when I try to run Atom after following [this guide](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/08/05/install-atom-text-editor-ubuntu-16-04/):

[image: screenshot showing Atom open next to a terminal window]

Comment: How do you launched atom? This screen is Inspect Element from Google-chrome, not atom itself

Comment: I tried running it by clicking the icon and it gave me that. When I go 'sudo atom' on the terminal it actually runs. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: You've likely made your `.atom` directory unwriteable **by** running it with `sudo` - see [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)

Comment: @steeldrive Thanks man, I will go read up on that.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue, you need to revert permissions to `.atom` config folder:

```
sudo chown <user>:<user> /home/<user>/.atom -hR
```

Seeing your image, I presume it's

```
sudo chown k:k /home/k/.atom -hR
```

---

If this doesn't solve it, I suggest you reinstall Atom using the [deb package](https://atom.io/download/deb) directly downloaded from [Atom](http://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/) site (that's how I installed in my computer):

```
sudo dpkg -i atom-amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

The last line is to install dependencies.

Comment: Hey Redbob, thanks for the solution.  sudo chown k:k /home/k/.atom -hR worked. :)

Comment: In my case using deb package was a solution. Thanks!